# Is it possible to export a single data without exporting all the data present in the db?

Tags: laravel, export, export-to-csv, laravel-9

I am trying to export the data present in my database; in particular all the clients present. So far there are no problems.

Now I would like to export to single client; I tried to set the code only that when I click to export the single client in an .xlsx file all clients are exported the same.
Here is my code:

**ClientsExport Class**

```
class ClientsExport implements FromCollection
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection(Client $client=NULL)
    {
        return Client::all();
    }
}
```

**ClientController**

```
public function export(Client $client=NULL) 
    {
        if($client){
            return Excel::download(new ClientsExport, $client->surname . ' ' .  $client->name . '.xlsx');
        } else {
            return Excel::download(new ClientsExport, 'clients.xlsx');            
        }
    }
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('client-export/{client?}', [ClientController::class,'export'])->name('client.export');
```

**View Blade**

> *Button where I want to export all clients (this works fine)*

```
<a class="btn btn-warning mb-5 py-3 px-4 mt-3 me-3 fs-5" href="{{ route('client.export') }}">Export all clients</a>
```

> *Button where I want to export the individual client (PROBLEM HERE)*

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ route('client.export' , compact('client')) }}">Export</a>
```

export fuction update:

```
 public function export(Client $client) 
    {
        if($client){
            dd($client);
            return Excel::download(new ClientsExport($client), $client->surname . ' ' .  $client->name . '.xlsx');
        } 
        return Excel::download(new ClientsExport, 'clients.xlsx');   
    }
```

Comment: Client::all(); will always return a collection with all records in clients table. To find just one record you must use a query like Clients::where('name', $name)->where('surname', $surname)->get(); 
Anyway it could return more than one record because the homonyms. So the only secure way should be a unique column like email, id, uuid or tax number. Regards

Comment: @Farid To pass the id how should I do?

Comment: Using id you'll return just the record belonging to that id. Eg: `return Client::findOrFail($id);`

Comment: And if there is no record with that `id` it will fire a not found exception.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Create the property on the export. Make it able to assign it on creation. While making the collection dependent on if the client is present or not.

```
class ClientsExport implements FromCollection
{
    private $client = null;

    public function __construct($client = null)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function collection(Client $client=NULL)
    {
        if ($this->client) {
            return collect([$this->client]);
        }

        return Client::all();
    }
}
```

When you call it you can pass the client and it will on creation filter the collection based on the logic we just created.

```
if ($client) {
    return Excel::download(new ClientsExport($client), $client->surname . ' ' .  $client->name . '.xlsx');
}
        
return Excel::download(new ClientsExport, 'clients.xlsx');
```

Comment: Tried but it always exports all clients when I try to export information for a single client

Comment: Then something is wrong, are you certain $client is passed to that route? dd($client); or dd() it in the export

Comment: in the ```dd($ client)``` placed before ```return Excel::download(new ClientsExport($client), $client->surname . ' ' .  $client->name . '.xlsx'); ``` the client of interest is printed correctly. The problem is definitely the next line

Comment: I put the export function in full in the question

Comment: What if you dd($this->client) in the collection method instead?

Comment: Just made an addition to the collection function as it should return a collection

Comment: perfect, now it works correctly. Can you kindly explain to me what is what you did last?

Comment: collection expects the returned type to be a collection, before it was only the model. There i wrapped the model into an collection, it was just an typo basically from my side :)

Comment: I ran into a small problem with your code. When I export all clients the file does not have the extension. Why does this happen to me?

Comment: Please, I need to fix this. I don't understand why the file is saved without extension

Comment: The code you included here have extension on both files. So if the name includes .xlsx it should be there. Or else try ->download('xls'); instead or whatever format you use

Comment: so what could be causing it? unfortunately this thing is happening to me

Comment: I tried to just leave `return Excel::download(new ClientsExport, 'clients.xlsx'); `  eliminating the rest and the extension is put without problems. The problem therefore is the if

Answer (score 0):

You are alwayse returning the same data from your `ClientsExport` Class, so you're not even using the `$client` valiable, instead you are accessing the static class `all()` of your Client model.

So to refactor this you need to use your injected client in your class

```
class ClientsExport implements FromCollection
{

    public function __construct ($client) 
    {
         $this->client = $client;
    }
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }
}
```

then in your controller check if the Client is set or not and return appropriate Client instance

```
public function export(Client $client) 
    {
        if($client->exists){
            return Excel::download(new ClientsExport($client),$client->surname . ' ' .  $client->name . '.xlsx');
        } 

        return Excel::download(new ClientsExport(User::all()), 'clients.xlsx');            
        
    }
```

Comment: trying your code i get **syntax error, unexpected token "}"** error in function export

Comment: @Sarah, semicolon is missing on the line ``$fileName = $client->surname . ' ' .  $client->name``

Comment: in function collection I get: Declaration of App\Exports\ClientsExport::collection(App\Models\Client $client) must be compatible with Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection::collection()

Comment: I always get the same error in collection function

Comment: if you are using laravel-excel package you may need to pass data from a constructor like https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html

Comment: clicking on the single customer, all information is always exported. I don't solve the problem unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

what is doing is first I get data from database of that particular user/client:

In Controller:

```
$data = CLIENT::where('id', $request->id)->get();
return Excel::download(new ExportUsers($data), $data->client_name. '.xlsx');
```

In Export class:

```
private $data;

public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}

public function collection(Client $client=NULL)
{
    return Client::where('id',$this->data->id)->get();
}
```

Try this I hope it work for you.

Comment: It does not work

Comment: I have a tutorial from which I have did and work fine for me.
https://medium.com/techvblogs/laravel-9-import-export-excel-csv-file-example-43855b3f0094

Comment: it is the same documentation that I have followed, but the problem that I am encountering concerns the export of the single client. Exporting all clients works for me too

Comment: That perfect now you have to pass id to your export class and then return a query like this: `Client::where('id',$this->data->id)->get();`